# Pyspark dataframe apply function to a row and add row to bottom of dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a df that only has one row.

```
id   |id2  |score|score2|
----------------------
0    |1    |4    |2     |
```

and i want to add a row of the percent of these to the bottom, i.e. every number divided by 7

```
0/7  |1/7  |4/7  |2/7   |
```

but the solution I came up with is incredibly slow

```
temp = [i/7 for i in df.collect()[0]]
row = sc.parallelize(Row(temp)).toDF()
df.union(row)
```

This took 21 seconds to run, almost all of which is the last two lines of code.  Is there a better way to do this?  My other thought was to transpose the table then this can easily be done with df.withColumn().  Ideally, I also want to filter out the column with 0, but I haven't really looked into that yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out and let me know if it helps

```
 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
 from pyspark.sql import functions as F

 spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName('practice')\
.getOrCreate()

 sc= spark.sparkContext

 df = sc.parallelize([
(0,1,4,2)]).toDF(["id", "id2","score","score2"])


df2 = df.select(*[(F.col(column)/7).alias(column) for column in df.columns])

df3 = df.union(df2)

df3.show()
+---+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
| id|                id2|             score|            score2|
+---+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
|0.0|                1.0|               4.0|               2.0|
|0.0|0.14285714285714285|0.5714285714285714|0.2857142857142857|
+---+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

If you want to. filter out the column having 0 you can use below code

```
non_zero_cols  = [c for c in df.columns if df[[c]].first()[c] > 0]

df1 = df.select(*non_zero_cols)

df2 = df1.select(*[(F.col(column)/7).alias(column) for column in 
df1.columns])

df3 = df1.union(df2)

df3.show()

+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
|                id2|             score|            score2|
+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
|                1.0|               4.0|               2.0|
|0.14285714285714285|0.5714285714285714|0.2857142857142857|
+-------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Please check the below code for  df having type column

```
non_zero_cols  = [c for c in df.columns if df[[c]].first()[c] > 0]

df1 = df.select(*non_zero_cols, F.lit('count').alias('type') )

df2 = df1.select(*[(F.col(column)/7).alias(column) for column in 
df1.columns if not column=='type'], F.lit('percent').alias('type'))

df3 = df1.union(df2)

df3.show()

+-------------------+------------------+------------------+-------+
|                id2|             score|            score2|   type|
+-------------------+------------------+------------------+-------+
|                1.0|               4.0|               2.0|  count|
|0.14285714285714285|0.5714285714285714|0.2857142857142857|percent|
+-------------------+------------------+------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! Is there a way to add a column to say what each row represents? Like column 'type' with entries 'count', 'percent'?